# How do I solve the following differential equation: $2xy + 1 + (x^2 + 2y)y' = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am struggling to solve the following differential equation. We are given the following: $$2xy + 1 + (x^2 + 2y)y' = 0,\;\;\;y(1) = -1.$$
So far, I tried moving the third term to the right side but I do not see how I could possibly use Separable Equation method to solve it. Perhaps, there is another method that I may be missing and I would appreciate any hint on how to move forward with this equation. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$2xy+x^2y'+2yy'=\frac{d}{dx}(x^2y+y^2).$$

So the equation is equivalent to:

$$\frac{d}{dx}(x^2y+y^2)=-1$$
$$\implies x^2y+y^2=-x+C$$
$$\implies y=\frac{-x^2\pm \sqrt{x^4-4x+4C}}{2}$$

$$y(1)=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{4C-3}}{2}=-1 \implies C=1$$
Since at $x=1$ the $\pm$ is $-$, and $y$ is differentiable at any point, the $\pm$ will always be $-$ at any point.
$$\therefore y=\frac{-x^2 - \sqrt{x^4-4x+4}}{2}$$

Comment: Thank you so much for walking through the process. At fist, I was confused how you got the left side equal to the right side in the first equation but now I understand that the left hand side is the result of taking derivative of the right side. Is there name for this method? It kinda looks like Integration factor method where you set a certain derivative of something equal to one side of the equation. What do you suggest I keep in mind when encountering these kinda equations?

Comment: For example, in 2x+y+(x+3y)y'=0, I see that we can do d/dx[xy+y^3] = -2x, right?

Comment: $2x+y+(x+3y^2)y'=0$ then that's right. I'm not sure whether there is a name for this, but I would say the best way would be to always keep in mind what you have learned about calculus, and look for where you can apply them in the equation so that it would become simpler. Spot the weakness and hunt it down. I am a student after all; this is just based on my experience... @DeepValue

Answer (score 0):

Your differential equation is an [exact differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_differential_equation). Indeed, you can check that $I(x, y) = 2xy + 1$ and $J(x, y) = x^2 + 2y$ are both continuously differentiable everywhere and
$$ \frac{\partial I}{\partial y} = 2x = \frac{\partial J}{\partial x}. $$
A general solution to an exact differential equation is $F(x, y) = C$ for constants $C$ (i.e., level curves of $F(x, y)$), where $F(x, y)$ is a potential function satisfying $\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial x} = I(x, y)$ and $\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial y} = J(x, y)$. Integrating $I(x, y)$ with respect to $x$, we obtain
$$ F(x, y) = x^2y + x + m(y). $$
Integrating $J(x, y)$ with respect to $y$, we obtain
$$ F(x, y) = x^2y + y^2 + n(x). $$
Equating the two expressions for $F(x, y)$, we see that
$$ x^2y + x + m(y) = x^2y + y^2 + n(x) \implies m(y) = y^2 \ \ \textrm{ and } \ \ n(x) = x. $$
Thus, a general solution to your differential equation is
$$ F(x, y) = x^2y + x + y^2 = C. $$
To find $C$, we impose the given initial condition $y(1) = -1$:
$$ -1 + 1 + 1 = 1 = C. $$
Thus, an implicit solution to your exact differential equation is
$$ x^2y + x + y^2 = 1. $$